# Simultaneous animation and fadeOut

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/UpLts/1/

This is just an example for illustrative purposes, but what I want to do is animate a box and fade it out simultaneously. What I have so far as you can see in the example, is an animation followed quickly by the fade. Can I make it fade while it is animating?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now you're using "animate" and "fadeTo", but you can do it all with "animate". In other words, you can "animate" multiple properties of your object with the "animate" function.
So, use: `box.stop(true, true).delay(100).animate({top:-0, opacity: 0},150);` instead.

Comment: That works, many thanks. I need to investigate what other properties can be combined with animate.

Comment: Andy, the jQuery docs is your friend =)
try here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/
And please, don't forget to mark one of the answers as the right one ok?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `opacity` of the elements:

```
c.mouseenter(function (){
     box.stop(true, true).delay(100).animate({top:-0, opacity: 0}, 150)
})
.mouseleave(function (){
     box.stop(true, true).delay(100).animate({top:40, opacity: 1}, 150)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're open to CSS solutions you can do it without JS - http://jsfiddle.net/UpLts/2/

```
.blocks {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px dotted #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.blocks_title {
    position: relative;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 40px;
    left: 40px;
    background: #333;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s;
       -moz-transition: all .25s;
            transition: all .25s;
}

.blocks:hover .blocks_title {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Excellent. I traditionally use jquery for animations but CSS is looking more like the way to go. Thanks.

Comment: @Andy Just keep in mind that this CSS3 awesomeness won't work in older IE-s, if that's a concern